# XSLT namespace error failed to parse qname

Tags: xslt, qnames

Good folks at stackoverflow... I am trying to create a XSLT transformation that will generate a Turtle file (RDF related).  Part of that involves output of prefixed namespaces, something like this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:sap_coda="http://www.sapmantics.com/sap_coda#"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>' .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
...
```

When I try to apply the transformation, I get:

```
$ xsltproc zcoda_ttl_v02x.xslt zcoda_data_v02.xml > zcoda_data_v02x.ttl | x.txt
zcoda_ttl_v02x.xslt:10: namespace error : Failed to parse QName 'http:'
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>' .
                    ^
zcoda_ttl_v02x.xslt:10: parser error : error parsing attribute name
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>' .
                    ^
zcoda_ttl_v02x.xslt:10: parser error : attributes construct error
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>' .
                    ^
zcoda_ttl_v02x.xslt:10: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag http: line 10
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>' .
```

So, I am at a loss here.  The Turtle output that I seek contains many of these cases.  Is there some way to stop the processor and just consider the http... as plain data (like the CDATA option in xml) ?  Thanks,  John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *entities*:

```
@prefix rdfs: &lt;http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#&gt;' .
@prefix owl: &lt;http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#&gt; .
@prefix dc: &lt;http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/&gt; .
```

Comment: I did try this, but my output now contains &lt; and &gt;, which is not my intent.  I need to have the output contain the actual < and > symbols.

Comment: @johnaco:  Either you're output is *text*, in which case you want `<xsl:output method="text" />` in your stylesheet, or it is *XML*, when literal `<` and `>` are invalid in PCDATA and you have to use the entities. A third possibility is that you're using CDATA, but please tell us if so.

Comment: Very nice.  That is what was missing - the output method="text".  With that, both methods described - using &lt &gt; or using the CDATA approach works as desired.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the http stuff in an xsl:text i guess:

```
 <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" 
                xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
                xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
                xmlns:sap_coda="http://www.sapmantics.com/sap_coda#" 
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
@prefix rdfs: <xsl:text><![CDATA[<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>]]></xsl:text>
```

Comment: Nope.  The output contains &lt; and &gt; for the < and > respectively.